# Dictionary<string, string> ou NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, dicionário, collection

Qual a diferença em usar `Dictionary<string, string>` e `NameValueCollection`?
Pesquisei, porém só encontrei em inglês no SOpt mesmo, usei o tradutor, porém a tradução ficou estranho e não entendi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A única coisa que precisa saber é: não use `NameValueCollection`. As coleções especializadas são praticamente obsoletas. Elas eram necessárias para o C# 1.0, com o advento das coleções genéricas, use-as no lugar. As especializadas não recebem mais carinho, provavelmente estão defasadas. Vai de `Dictionary`.

Existe uma diferença, já que a segunda é um multi mapa permitindo ter vários valores com a mesma chave. Mas se precisa disto, e geralmente não precisa, então você quer usar a [`Lookup`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).